# Files cannot be renamed or removed, they reappear after unmount/mount

Tags: mac, partitioning, format

I am unable to format my SDXC card. I have tried all the ways I could come up with, including but not limited to;

- mac disk utility:

  - verify + repair disk
  - Erase partition (zero out, 3 pass, 7 pass)
  - Create new partition table (both with mbr and GUID)

screenshot:

[image]

- terminal:

  - sudo `rm -rf /Volumes/untitled/*`

Then I isolated the problem to my music folder. In the folder I've found out there are files with illegal characters as file names. So I used the `mv` command and various apps that help rename files but each time I erase them and unmount whenever I mount the files come back.

screenshot:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We also tried `dd` to zero out the entire sd card from an ubuntu live cd but to no avail.

I've henceforth called the sd card 'broken' and its now stuck to a balloon and will be released this weekend to float freely and die upon impact on the ground/sea. The little bugger wont be missed.